# Computational tractability of algorithm for matching names in two files in python

Tags: python

So I have two .txt files that I'm trying to match up.  The first .txt file is just lines of about 12,500 names.

```
John Smith
Jane Smith
Joe Smith
```

The second .txt file also contains lines with names (that might repeat) but also extra info, about 17GB total.

```
584 19423   john smith  John Smith  79946792    5   5   11  2016-06-24
584 19434   john smith  John Smith  79923732    5   4   11  2018-03-14
584 19423   jane smith  Jane Smith  79946792    5   5   11  2016-06-24
```

My goal is to find all the names from File 1 in File 2, and then spit out the File 2 lines that contain any of those File 1 names.

Here is my python code:

```
with open("Documents/File1.txt", "r") as t:
    terms = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in t]
with open("Documents/File2.txt", "r") as f, open("Documents/matched.txt","w") as w: 
    for line in f:
        if any([term in line for term in terms]):
            w.write(line)
```

So this code definitely works, but it has been running for 3 days (and is still going!!!).  I did some back-of-the-envelope calculations, and I'm very worried that my algorithm is computationally intractable (or hyper inefficient) given the size of the data.

Would anyone be able to provide feedback re: (1) whether this is actually intractable and/or extremely inefficient and if so (2) what an alternative algorithm might be?

Thank you!!

Comment: the bottleneck is here: `any([term in line for term in terms])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when testing membership, `set` and `dict` are going to be much, much faster, so `terms` should be a `set`:

```py
with open("Documents/File1.txt", "r") as t:
    terms = set(line.strip() for line in t)
```

Next, I would split each line into a list, and check if the name is in the set, not if members of the set are in the line, which is O(N) where N is the length of each line. This way you can directly pick out the column numbers (via slicing) that contain the first and last name:

```py
with open("Documents/File2.txt", "r") as f, open("Documents/matched.txt","w") as w: 
    for line in f:
        # split the line on whitespace
        names = line.split()

        # Your names seem to occur here
        name = ' '.join(names[4:6])

        if name in terms:
            w.write(line)
```